# How can I add minute to a custom DateComponent in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make an alarm app, where the app downloads alarm time from firebase. Now the will have to go consecutively 5 times with 1 minute time interval in between them. One possible way to tackle this problem is to make increment the time on the date component that's being passed in UNCalendarNotifications. Unfortunately DateComponent doesn't have a function to increment time, but date does.. and I can't figure out how to increment the time in given date component.

NB: I have tried converting date object to date and then increment time. But looks like Date only does it with current time.

Comment: Show some relevant code in your question. Clearly explain what you need help with. Show example input and desired output.

Answer (score -1):

You do not have to do anything with the date just check if the timestamp reached for the alarm to start then use a timer for repeat if 5 times.
Here is the code hope this help.

```
var timer:Timer?
var timeLeft = 60

timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(onTimerFires), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

@objc func onTimerFires()
{
    timeLeft -= 1
    if timeLeft <= 0 {
        timer.invalidate()
        timer = nil
        //TODO: ring the alarm now
    }
}
```